# Split string into two arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to split a string into two arrays:

```
string foo = "apple;carrot";
```

I want to put "apple" into one array, and "carrot" in another array.

Just using 
`foo.Split(;)` would result in both words being put into the same array, one after each other.

I hope I made myself clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want two words into separate arrays? could the string be larger separated by `;` ? if so how do you want the result?

Answer (score 8):

You would need to project the array to a new array for each item:

```
string foo = "apple;carrot";
var collection = foo.Split(';').Select(x=> new String[] { x });
```

This will return you `IEnumerable<String[]>` which you can iterate.

```
foreach(var array in collection)
{
  // do something with array
}
```

Or you can create an array of arrays like this:

```
var arrays = collection.ToArray();
```

Comment: Why don't you use ToArray?

Comment: @AlKepp user needs each item in different array, not in one

Comment: I mean to use ToArray together with other parts to get a collection of char[] arrays. Because he wanted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var splits = foo.Split( new char[]{ ';' });
```